# QComboBox multiple selection - PyQT5

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pyqt, gui, pyqt5

I'm making the gui for my QGIS3 plugin using PyQT5 and QT designer. I have a very long list of items in a `QComboBox` and I need the user to be able to select one or more items. I know that `QComboBox` allows only single selection, so I thought that I can use `QListWidget`. The problem is that the list of selectable items is very long and I'd need a dropdown menu or something similar.

Is there a way to style a `QListWidget` like a `QComboBox` or to allow a multiple selection using `QComboBox`?

EDIT: I added an immage of my GUI. This is a long list and, as you can see, it's the reason why I can't use `QListWidget` or `QTableWidget`. A dropdown checkbox group should be perfect and I'm surprised that QT doesn't make this available.

[image]

Comment: I think that the list widget is the component thought for your problem (multiple selection). Remember that you can give it a reasonable small height and the widget will scroll.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It would be useful for the user to see all the elements simultaneously, this is the principal reason why I asked for a dropdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is an implementation of a CheckableComboBox.

```
class CheckableComboBox(QComboBox):

    # Subclass Delegate to increase item height
    class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        def sizeHint(self, option, index):
            size = super().sizeHint(option, index)
            size.setHeight(20)
            return size

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make the combo editable to set a custom text, but readonly
        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        # Make the lineedit the same color as QPushButton
        palette = qApp.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, palette.button())
        self.lineEdit().setPalette(palette)

        # Use custom delegate
        self.setItemDelegate(CheckableComboBox.Delegate())

        # Update the text when an item is toggled
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateText)

        # Hide and show popup when clicking the line edit
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False

        # Prevent popup from closing when clicking on an item
        self.view().viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Recompute text to elide as needed
        self.updateText()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):

        if object == self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                if self.closeOnLineEditClick:
                    self.hidePopup()
                else:
                    self.showPopup()
                return True
            return False

        if object == self.view().viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                index = self.view().indexAt(event.pos())
                item = self.model().item(index.row())

                if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
                else:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
                return True
        return False

    def showPopup(self):
        super().showPopup()
        # When the popup is displayed, a click on the lineedit should close it
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = True

    def hidePopup(self):
        super().hidePopup()
        # Used to prevent immediate reopening when clicking on the lineEdit
        self.startTimer(100)
        # Refresh the display text when closing
        self.updateText()

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        # After timeout, kill timer, and reenable click on line edit
        self.killTimer(event.timerId())
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False

    def updateText(self):
        texts = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                texts.append(self.model().item(i).text())
        text = ", ".join(texts)

        # Compute elided text (with "...")
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.lineEdit().font())
        elidedText = metrics.elidedText(text, Qt.ElideRight, self.lineEdit().width())
        self.lineEdit().setText(elidedText)

    def addItem(self, text, data=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if data is None:
            item.setData(text)
        else:
            item.setData(data)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)

    def addItems(self, texts, datalist=None):
        for i, text in enumerate(texts):
            try:
                data = datalist[i]
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text, data)

    def currentData(self):
        # Return the list of selected items data
        res = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                res.append(self.model().item(i).data())
        return res
```

### Usage

```
comunes = ['Ameglia', 'Arcola', 'Bagnone', 'Bolano', 'Carrara', 'Casola', 'Castelnuovo Magra', 
    'Comano, località Crespiano', 'Fivizzano', 'Fivizzano località Pieve S. Paolo', 
    'Fivizzano località Pieve di Viano', 'Fivizzano località Soliera', 'Fosdinovo', 'Genova', 
    'La Spezia', 'Levanto', 'Licciana Nardi', 'Lucca', 'Lusuolo', 'Massa', 'Minucciano', 
    'Montignoso', 'Ortonovo', 'Piazza al sercho', 'Pietrasanta', 'Pignine', 'Pisa',
    'Podenzana', 'Pontremoli', 'Portovenere', 'Santo Stefano di Magra', 'Sarzana',
    'Serravezza', 'Sesta Godano', 'Varese Ligure', 'Vezzano Ligure', 'Zignago' ]
combo = CheckableComboBox()
combo.addItems(comunes)
```

### Result

[image: Checkable ComboBox]

---

### Edit

QGIS defines its own QgsCheckableCombobox, which is unfortunately broken (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28658).

It relies on the QCombBox activated signal to toggle on/off its items. The problem is that this signal is emitted when the combobox is opened and there's a single selected item, which is NOT the currentIndex

It's however possible to fix it, albeit in a slightly hackish way

```
class CheckableComboBox2(QgsCheckableComboBox):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.activated.connect(self.afterActivated)   

    def afterActivated(self):
        for i in range ( self.model().rowCount()):
            item = self.model().item(i)  
            if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                self.setCurrentIndex(i)
                self.model().itemCheckStateChanged.emit()
                return
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do you know https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCheckableComboBox.html ? There is one issue, maybe you could spot it in the code? https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28658

Comment: No I was not aware of this Class. From what I understand, it relies on the QCombBox activated signal to toggle on/off its items. The problem is that this signal is emitted when the combobox is opened and there's a single selected item, which is NOT the currentIndex. A solution would be to set the currentIndex to the first selected item in QgsCheckableComboBox::setItemCheckState when an item is toggled off.

Comment: ok thanks for looking. Feel free to do a PR if you can. Can you add your answer on the Github ticket too. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you made an answer there.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks again

Comment: May be of interest to those who used the above code: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/471463/143494

Answer (score 3):

You're right. **QComboBox** objects allow only single selection because they don't have **ExtendedSelection** option (as **QListWidget** objects) for activating multiple selection. However, you can also use a **QTableWidget** object whose **ExtendedSelection** option is already activated by default. In following code you have an example.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Dlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()

        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3,"Tab3")

        layer = iface.activeLayer()

        nf = layer.fields().names()

        feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

        data = [ [] for i in range(len(feats)) ]

        nb_row = len(feats)
        nb_col = len(nf)

        for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
            for j in range(nb_col):
                data[i].append(feat.attribute(nf[j]))

        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table1 = QTableWidget()
        self.table1.setRowCount(nb_row)
        self.table1.setColumnCount(nb_col)
        self.table1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(nf)

        for row in range (nb_row):
            for col in range(nb_col):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
                self.table1.setItem(row, col, item)

        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.table1)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs, 0, 0)

w = Dlg()
w.resize(350,300)
w.setWindowTitle('Example with QTableWidget')
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
w.show()
```

I used it for printed in this kind of object (**QTableWidget**) the values of each field in attributes Table of active layer; as it can be observed in following image.

[image]

In following images it can be observed multiple selection by rows:

[image]

or by columns:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Why can you not use a **QTableWidget**? I modified above code for including your long list and some labels for creating a similar context with your form. Code looks as follows:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Dlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel('Visualizzare tutti i beni per:')
        self.label2 = QLabel('Macro-epoca originaria:')

        comunes = ['Ameglia', 'Arcola', 'Bagnone', 'Bolano', 'Carrara', 'Casola', 'Castelnuovo Magra',
                   'Comano, località Crespiano', 'Fivizzano', 'Fivizzano località Pieve S. Paolo', 
                   'Fivizzano località Pieve di Viano', 'Fivizzano località Soliera', 'Fosdinovo'
                   'Genova', 'La Spezia', 'Levanto', 'Licciana Nardi', 'Lucca', 'Lusuolo', 'Massa',
                   'Minucciano', 'Montignoso', 'Ortonovo', 'Piazza al sercho', 'Pietrasanta', 'Pignine',
                   'Pisa', 'Podenzana', 'Pontremoli', 'Portovenere', 'Santo Stefano di Magra', 'Sarzana',
                   'Serravezza', 'Sesta Godano', 'Varese Ligure', 'Vezzano Ligure', 'Zignago' ]

        nb_row = len(comunes)
        nb_col = 1

        data = [ [] for i in range(nb_row) ]

        for i, comune in enumerate(comunes):
            for j in range(nb_col):
                data[i].append(comune)

        self.table1 = QTableWidget()
        self.table1.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.table1.setRowCount(nb_row)
        self.table1.setColumnCount(nb_col)
        self.table1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Comune'])

        for row in range (nb_row):
            for col in range(nb_col):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(data[row][col]))
                self.table1.setItem(row, col, item)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table1, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2, 2, 0)

w = Dlg()
w.resize(350,300)
w.setWindowTitle('Ricerca beni')
w.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
w.show()
```

After running it, you can observe in following image that it is possible to scroll all 36 items and to realize multiple selection with them. You can also use the hide mode with the **QTableWidget** for visualizing options by using a check button (yor desired dropdown checkbox group).

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please, see my editing note.

Comment: Hi many thanks again. My ideas now are quite more clear and I'll probably use your solution. I had not thought to hide it. In this way I could keep reduced the dialog's size.

Answer (score 0):

Completely similar answer to Yoann Quenach de Quivillic's  `CheckableComboBox`, but for PyQt6:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QEvent

from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QFontMetrics

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QComboBox, QStyledItemDelegate

class MultiComboBox(QComboBox):
    # Subclass Delegate to increase item height
    class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        def sizeHint(self, option, index):
            size = super().sizeHint(option, index)
            size.setHeight(20)
            return size

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make the combo editable to set a custom text, but readonly
        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)

        # Use custom delegate
        self.setItemDelegate(MultiComboBox.Delegate())

        # Update the text when an item is toggled
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateText)

        # Hide and show popup when clicking the line edit
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False

        # NOTE: this is commented since in PyQt6 seems to 
        # cause an issue: it prevents the program process from
        # being terminated, forcing a keyboard interrupt (or
        # equivalent)
        # Prevent popup from closing when clicking on an item
        # self.view().viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Recompute text to elide as needed
        self.updateText()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if object == self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                if self.closeOnLineEditClick:
                    self.hidePopup()
                else:
                    self.showPopup()
                return True
            return False

        if object == self.view().viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                index = self.view().indexAt(event.pos())
                item = self.model().item(index.row())

                if item.checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)
                else:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Checked)
                return True
        return False

    def showPopup(self):
        super().showPopup()
        # When the popup is displayed, a click on the lineedit should close it
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = True

    def hidePopup(self):
        super().hidePopup()
        # Used to prevent immediate reopening when clicking on the lineEdit
        self.startTimer(100)
        # Refresh the display text when closing
        self.updateText()

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        # After timeout, kill timer, and reenable click on line edit
        self.killTimer(event.timerId())
        self.closeOnLineEditClick = False

    def updateText(self):
        texts = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                texts.append(self.model().item(i).text())
        text = ", ".join(texts)

        # Compute elided text (with "...")
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.lineEdit().font())
        elidedText = metrics.elidedText(text, Qt.TextElideMode.ElideRight, self.lineEdit().width())
        self.lineEdit().setText(elidedText)

    def addItem(self, text, data=None):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if data is None:
            item.setData(text)
        else:
            item.setData(data)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked, Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)

    def addItems(self, texts, datalist=None):
        for i, text in enumerate(texts):
            try:
                data = datalist[i]
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text, data)

    def currentData(self):
        res = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                res.append(self.model().item(i).data())
        return res

    def currentOptions(self):
        res = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:
                res.append((self.model().item(i).text(),
                            self.model().item(i).data()))
        return res
```

Comment: May be of interest: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/471463/143494

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked what I believe was derived from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351152/143494) answer above, and made it a lot less (or entirely not) buggy.

You can add new items via. the text box, change what's selected in the text box, and also even go back and forth between using the text box and the dropdown checkboxes seamlessly. I also added a delete button which will delete what's selected. I like this functionality a lot better:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class CheckableComboBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.combo_box = CheckableComboBoxChild(self)

        self.delete_btn = QPushButton("Delete Selected")
        self.delete_btn.clicked.connect(self.combo_box.deleteSelected)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)
        layout.addWidget(self.delete_btn)

class CheckableComboBoxChild(QComboBox):
    # Subclass Delegate to increase item height
    class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
        def sizeHint(self, option, index):
            size = super().sizeHint(option, index)
            size.setHeight(20)
            return size

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Make the combo editable to set a custom text
        self.setEditable(True)
        self.setInsertPolicy(QComboBox.NoInsert)
        self.lineEdit().setPlaceholderText("--Select Actions--")
        edit = self.lineEdit()
        self.setLineEdit(edit)
        #self.completer = QCompleter()
        #self.completer.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
        #self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        #edit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        #self.completer.setModel(self.model())
        edit.returnPressed.connect(self.insertCustomItem)

        # Make the lineedit the same color as QPushButton
        palette = qApp.palette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Base, palette.button())
        self.lineEdit().setPalette(palette)

        # Use custom delegate
        self.setItemDelegate(CheckableComboBoxChild.Delegate())

        # Update the text when an item is toggled
        self.model().dataChanged.connect(self.updateText)

        # Hide and show popup when clicking the line edit
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)

        # Prevent popup from closing when clicking on an item
        self.view().viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Recompute text to elide as needed
        self.updateText()
        super().resizeEvent(event)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if object == self.view().viewport():
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                if self.lineEdit().hasFocus():
                    return True
                index = self.view().indexAt(event.pos())
                item = self.model().item(index.row())
                if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
                else:
                    item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
                return False
        return False

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        # After timeout, kill timer, and reenable click on line edit
        self.killTimer(event.timerId())

    def updateText(self):
        texts = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                texts.append(self.model().item(i).text())
        text = ", ".join(texts)

        # Compute elided text (with "...")
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.lineEdit().font())
        elidedText = metrics.elidedText(text, Qt.ElideRight, self.lineEdit().width())
        self.lineEdit().setText(elidedText)

    def addItem(self, text, data=None, checked=False):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setText(text)
        if data is None:
            item.setData(text)
        else:
            item.setData(data)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked if not checked else Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        self.model().appendRow(item)

    def addItems(self, texts, datalist=None):
        for i, text in enumerate(texts):
            try:
                data = datalist[i]
            except (TypeError, IndexError):
                data = None
            self.addItem(text, data)

    def insertCustomItem(self):
        text = self.lineEdit().text().strip()
        # Split the text by comma, and lowercase and strip() each piece
        typedItemsOriginal = [item.strip() for item in text.split(",") if item.strip()]
        typedItemsLower = [item.lower() for item in typedItemsOriginal]
        # Uncheck all items
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            self.model().item(i).setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        # Loop through each item in the text and check it, if it exists in
        # lowercase
        for i in range(len(typedItemsOriginal)):
            for j in range(self.model().rowCount()):
                if self.model().item(j).text().lower() == typedItemsLower[i]:
                    self.model().item(j).setData(Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
                    break
            else:
                # If the item doesn't exist, add it to the list
                self.addItem(typedItemsOriginal[i], checked=True)
        self.updateText()
        self.showPopup()

    def currentData(self):
        # Return the list of selected items data
        res = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            if self.model().item(i).checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                res.append(self.model().item(i).data())
        return res

    def deleteSelected(self):
        text = self.lineEdit().text().strip()
        # Split the text by comma, and lowercase and strip() each piece
        checked_items = [item.strip() for item in text.split(",") if item.strip()]
        if not checked_items:
            QMessageBox.information(self, "No Selection", "No options were selected, to delete!")
            return
        confirmDeletion = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Confirm Deletion', f"Are you sure you want to delete {', '.join(checked_items)}?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        anyRemoved = False
        if confirmDeletion == QMessageBox.Yes:
            for item in checked_items:
                index = self.findText(item)
                if index != -1:
                    self.removeItem(index)
                    anyRemoved = True
        if anyRemoved:
          self.updateText()
          self.showPopup()
```

---

To use it, put it in a file named `ComboBoxWidget.py` and then do this:

```py
import ComboBoxWidget

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set layout of window
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # Add editable, multiselect checkbox
        self.actions = ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5' ]
        self.action_group = []
        self.combo = ComboBoxWidget.CheckableComboBox()
        self.combo.combo_box.addItems(self.actions)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.combo)
```